# getting "T is undefined" error when trying to loop through an array of layers to add to a webmap

Tags: javascript, loops, geojson, layer

Okay so I have created a page with 8 geojson layers and 8 marker layers. I have it so one geojson layer and one marker at a time is triggered by a button on the page. Only one geojson layer and one marker layer can displayed at a time, as I have used a loop to delete all other layers.

I have also added a resetMap function which corresponds to a button on the page, which loops through an array of all layers and deletes them from the map if they are displayed.

Now I am trying to make a showAllLayers function which corresponds to another button on the page, which will display all my layers by looping through an array of all my layers and display them if they are not already, but it just doesn't work!!

The function looks like this:

```
function showAllLayers() {

        let layers = [Frog1Layer, Frog2Layer, Frog3Layer, Frog4Layer, Frog5Layer, Frog6Layer, Frog7Layer, Frog8Layer,
        Frog1Marker, Frog2Marker, Frog3Marker, Frog4Marker, Frog5Marker, Frog6Marker, Frog7Marker, Frog8Marker]

        for (let i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        map.addLayer(layers[i]);
        }
    }
```

the error in the console reads as follows:

> TypeError: t is undefined4 leaflet.js:5:64519
>        addLayer https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js:5
>       showAllLayers file:///F:/GIS Assessment 1/MyScript.js:523
>       onclick file:///F:/GIS Assessment 1/ATTEMPT01.html:1

so it seems the issue is with the addLayer feature.

Each of my layers is set as a global variable and looks like this:

```
Frog1Layer = L.geoJson(Frog1, { 
                    style: {
                        weight:         0.5,
                        color:          'white',
                        fillOpacity:    1,
                        fillColor:      'red',
                    }

Frog1Marker = L.marker([9.706891,-83.667942],
```

Can anyone figure out what's wrong? I've been stumped for ages on this, as my other arrays work fine but every single way I've tried to use the addLayer feature to show all my layers at once seems to call this error.

Comment: There is no `t` in the code you have provided. Do you have any variable with that name in your code?

Comment: no!! i don't use t?? it seems to be coming from the Leaflet file, but I don't understand why.

Comment: It's impossible to reproduce the error with the code you have provided  if you do not make a demo so others are able to see the cause.